# Pulling news articles from sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to pull news articles added on a sharepoint online page so that we can use it at other places using an API? I can't seem to figure out how to get the data using an API. I have read graph is also an option but I am not sure how to use that either. If anyone has any ideas that would be very helpful.
Sharepoint online url -
https:/.sharepoint.com/sites//SitePages/News-Room.aspx
Thank you!!

I have tried multiple api urls based on what I read here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-the-sharepoint-news-using-rest-api-in-spfx/
but they don't seem to give me the news feed data.

Comment: Are you trying to get the new titles and new page links or actual content/web parts on the news pages?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is impossible in SharePoint Online to pull contents from page using API. You have to remove the articles to a document library and get library items using REST/Graph API.